# Ruby On Rails form error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm making a form in my web app, that has to be filled, else I want to display an error message on the page. I followed some tutorials, but I'm encountering an issue : when I submit this form, the app is returning on the previous page without displaying the error message because the form is empty.

Here is my html.erb :

```
<%= form_for @task do |f| %>
  <%= render 'shared/add_task_error_messages' %>
  <%= f.text_field :title, :class => "col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4 field", :placeholder => "Title", :maxlength => "80" %></br>
  <%= f.text_field :department, :class => "col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4 field", :placeholder => "Department", :maxlength => "80" %></br>
  <%= f.text_field :startDate, :class => "col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4 datepicker", :placeholder => "Start date", :maxlength => "80" %></br>
  <%= f.text_field :endDate, :class => "col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4 datepicker", :placeholder => "End date", :maxlength => "80" %></br>
  <%= f.submit :Submit, :value => "Create", :class => "col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-5", :id => "create_task" %>
<% end %>
```

my controller methods :

```
def create
  @task = Task.new(task_params)
  if @task.save
    redirect_to @task
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

private

def task_params
    params.require(:task).permit(:title, :department, :startDate, :endDate)
end
```

and the '_add_task_error_messages.html.erb' file with the error message :

```
<% if @task.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
      The form contains <%= pluralize(@task.errors.count, "error") %>.
    </div>
    <ul>
    <% @task.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

and the model :

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates :title, :presence => true
  validates :department, :presence => true
  validates :startDate, :presence => true
  validates :endDate, :presence => true

  # Returns tasks array of the project
  def self.getProjectTasks
    projectTasks = Array.new
    result = Task.where("identifier = ?", 1)
    (1..result.length).each do |i|
      task = Array.new
      task.push(result.find(i).title)
      task.push(result.find(i).department)
      task.push(result.find(i).content)
      task.push(result.find(i).duration)
      task.push(result.find(i).startDate)
      task.push(result.find(i).endDate)
      projectTasks.push(task)
    end
    return projectTasks
  end

end
```

UPDATE :

In fact, I'm getting an error when the app is returning on the 'new' page when the form is submitted, without showing the error message.
When it go on this 'new' page, I'm getting an error on the html.erb because I have an object which has to be initialized. Here is the 'new' page :

```
<div class="tasks">
  <% @projectTasks.each do |task| %> # The error is here, "undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass"
    <div class="task col-lg-8">
      <div class="details">
        <div class="detail"><%= task[0] %></div>
        <div class="detail"><%= task[1] %></div>
        <div class="detail"><%= task[3] %> days</div>
        <div class="detail"><%= task[4] %> - <%= task[5] %></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

but this error is only showing when the app is redirecting after the submitted form, and I don't want it to display the 'new' page, I only want to stay on my form with the error message of the empty form.

Comment: Hey @Karz, check my answer below and let me know if it is working or not.

Comment: What are the validations in your Task model?

Comment: Maybe your task was saved successfully that's why you're not getting any errors.
You can test that by raising something in `if @task.save`

Comment: @RaVeN I checked and it's going through. I update my question with the model.

Comment: @Karz What do your logs look like once you send the form? Maybe they'll have some useful information to debug this.

Comment: As per your new edit, you'll need to set @projectTasks (to the value you set it to in the new action of the controller) in the else block of the create action, before you do `render 'new'`.

Comment: @Vishal : Here is the log for the form post :                                                                      `Started POST "/tasks" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-03-18 12:02:26 +0100
Processing by TasksController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"V", "authenticity_token"=>"RIeF4JUNrepNTxcu0oL38aLh262W4
TOupylNfqN4wqk=", "task"=>{"title"=>"", "department"=>"", "startDate"=>"", "endD
ate"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create"}
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
  Rendered tasks/new.html.erb within layouts/application (2.0ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 10ms`

Comment: @RaVeN I'm only getting datas in my bdd, thanks for the link.

Comment: Thanks @Vishal the redirection works great, but I want to see error messages because my form is empty.

Comment: What's the code in the else block of create action? Are you redirecting or rendering in there?

Comment: I'm making 'render new' and it brings me to this html page.

Answer (score 2):

Your file must be:

```
_add_task_error_messages.html.erb
```

Not:

```
add_task_error_messages.html.erb
```

Filename must have underscore first because it is a partial. And be sure that it is on `app/views/shared/_add_task_error_messages.htm.erb` path.

UPDATE:

Try to pass the object within you rendering.

Change:

```
<%= render 'shared/add_task_error_messages' %>
```

To:

```
<%= render 'shared/add_task_error_messages', task: @task %>
```

And in `_add_task_error_message.html.erb` it must be:

```
<% if task.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
      The form contains <%= pluralize(task.errors.count, "error") %>.
    </div>
    <ul>
    <% task.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: It's not working, it's going on the 'new' page again

Comment: @Karz, see  UPDATE on my answer. Try to pass the object within your rendering partial and call the object to partial.

Comment: Try to change `@task.errors.any?` to `task.errors.any?` and `@task` to `task` in `_add_task_error_message.html.erb`.  I updated again the answer. Tell me if it is still not working and tell what the error says.